# Como paralelizar a compilação com make?

Tags: linux, compilação, makefile

O processo de compilação é paralelizável, mas por padrão o programa `make` executa uma receita por vez. Como pararelizar a compilação com o `make`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A opção `-j` (ou `--jobs`) define quantos comandos devem ser executados em paralelo.

Por exemplo, `make -j8` irá executar 8 comandos em paralelo.

Para definir este comportamento como padrão, modifique a variável de ambiente `MAKEFLAGS`:

```
setenv MAKEFLAGS '-j8'
```

Geralmente [recomenda-se](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2500791/604734) um valor de `n+1` para `j`, onde `n` é o número de núcleos disponíveis.